# Button group loses style when I connect it with NavLink

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Good evening. I'd like to use the Material UI Button group component, but when using NavLink inside each button, it doesn't preserve styles.
[Image preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdDX7.png)

And how do I have the component:

```
export default function BasicButtonGroup() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <ButtonGroup color="primary" aria-label="outlined primary button group">
        <NavLink to="/one/" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
          <Button>One</Button>
        </NavLink>
        <Button>Two</Button>
        <Button>Three</Button>
      </ButtonGroup>
    </div>
  );
}
```